# Joining tables with GROUP BY in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, grouping, st-geometry

I have a layer "Table1" and an attribute table "Table 2" both stored in a PostgreSQL enterprise geodatabase, these 2 data have one field in common for which the cardinality of the relationship is one to many; 'each feature from Table 1 has many rows in Table 2'.
I am kind of trying to do the equivalent of the summarise tool from ArcGIS Pro and perform a join at the same time, which is creating a view from joining the two datasources and using the clause GROUP BY in order to group by 2 other diffrent fields from the attribute table.

My query fails because I have to aggregate the field shape into an aggregation function.

Any ideas on how I can aggregate the field shape?

I tried this solution but it's not working:

```
SELECT Table1.objectid,
   Table1.name,
   sde.st_astext(sde.st_aggr_union(Table1.shape))AS UNION_SHAPE,
   Avg(Table2.ecart),
   Table2.code
   FROM   Table1
   INNER JOIN Table2
          ON Table1.name = Table2.retard      
   GROUP  BY (Table2.objectid,
      Table1.name,
      Table2.code      
     )
```

Here's the error I am getting :

Underlying DBMS Error [ERROR: Column 'Table1.shape' must appear in GROUP BY clause or must be used in an aggregate function at character 62::SQLSTATE=42803]

Comment: Did you really name your tables "i" and "r"? That is extraordinarily bad practice. You have 31 characters to use, and using 8-20 of them (and a schema) is best practice.

Comment: No I did not, i just kept the first letter of the table name for anonymity while writing this post.

Comment: Better to spell out `table1 i` than redact into confusion. Geometry aggregation makes no sense with an objectid in the query. You don't report the error, so it's exceedingly difficult to help. Note that this has nothing to do with Pro -- it's an enterprise geodatabase question.

Comment: I edited my post and I included the error I am getting. First I didn't include the error because I am not sure that my query is correct.

Comment: You need to better describe the task. and the relationships between the tables. It's a serious mistake to aggregate a geometry with itself to get the original geometry (***very*** expensive). Far better to make a virtual table of the join, then join back to pick up the geometry by objectid.

Comment: What you have right now is going to return duplicate objectid values, which will make the result unusable from ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: If you describe the task (the tables and the relationship between them (including cardinality), and what you expect to get out of the query), we can help. Right now, the code is not sufficient to explain the intended result.

Comment: I edited my question and tried to describe the task i would like to accomplish, I hope I am clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139302/discussion-between-mar-and-vince).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the key to working with geometry and grouping is to avoid it -- only get the stuff you need up front in a virtual table, then go back for whatever else you need via JOIN.

```sql
SELECT 
   vt.objectid,
   v1.name,
   sde.ST_AsText(v1.shape) AS wkt,
   avg_ecart,
   vt.code
FROM (
   SELECT     t1.objectid,t2.code,avg(t2.ecart) as avg_ecart
   FROM       table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
           ON t2.retard = t1.name      
   GROUP  BY  t1.objectid,t2.code
) vt
JOIN table1 v1 on v1.objectid = vt.objectid
```

Note that this will return duplicate `objectid` values, and the geometry will be in WKT.

You can use `row_number` to generate unique values, but for reliability you would need an ORDER BY to force the same return order in successive queries:

```sql
SELECT 
   vt.vobjid,
   v1.name,
   v1.shape, -- sde.ST_AsText(v1.shape) AS wkt,
   vt.avg_ecart,
   vt.code
FROM (
   SELECT     t1.objectid,t2.code,avg(t2.ecart) as avg_ecart,
              (row_number() over(ORDER BY t1.objectid,t2.code))::integer as vobjid,
   FROM       table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
           ON t2.retard = t1.name      
   GROUP  BY  t1.objectid,t2.code
) vt
JOIN table1 v1 on v1.objectid = vt.objectid
```

Comment: The first query is throwing the same error i had before : Underlying DBMS Error [ERROR: Column 'wkt' has pseudo type cstring::SQLSTATE=42P16]

The second one is also not working

Comment: I doubt you can return the WKT to the ArcGIS client, even if you cast it to `text`.  Return the geometry (v1.shape) instead.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you mean.

Comment: I haven't tested this, since I use PostGIS geometry exclusively (AWS RDS), but returning the geometry directly should work.  Note that this kind of a view won't work at all if the feature class is versioned.

Comment: Yes i returned the geometry (v1.shape) instead and it's working. Thank you so much for your help.